# SSRS2008 Report SOAP OutOfMemoryException in IE8

Tags: soap, internet-explorer-8, ssrs-2008

I have an MVC3 website that uses SOAP to run a reporting services report and this is then returned to the browser. The users have IE8 on their machines and all the reports run fine except for one particular report that is throwing an error. The report takes 3 parameters and returns a table with < 10 rows. It only throws the error in IE8 when the number of rows is > 0. If the number of rows = 0 then it will return the report with just the headings. The report runs fine in ReportManager and FireFox. I have searched the web and StackOverflow looking for an answer with no success. The problem is I am not 100% sure whether it is a SOAP or SSRS problem or even something else and was hoping for some guidance.

**IE8 Error**

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. ---> System.Exception: For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Grj.Rail.Services.Reporting.ReportExecutionServiceSoap.LoadReport(LoadReportRequest request)
   at Grj.Rail.Services.Reporting.ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient.LoadReport(TrustedUserHeader TrustedUserHeader, String Report, String HistoryID, ServerInfoHeader& ServerInfoHeader, ExecutionInfo& executionInfo) in C:\VS Projects\Grj\Source Code\Rail\Source\trunk\Grj.Rail.Services\Service References\Reporting\Reference.cs:line 3248
   at Grj.Rail.Services.Impl.ReportService.InnerGetReport(String report, ParameterValue[] parameters, Byte[]& output, String& extension, String& mimeType, String& encoding, Warning[]& warnings, String[]& streamIds, String format) in C:\VS Projects\Grj\Source Code\Rail\Source\trunk\Grj.Rail.Services\Impl\ReportService.cs:line 86
   at Grj.Rail.Services.Impl.ReportService.GetReport(String report, ReportTypes reportType, IDictionary`2 parameters) in C:\VS Projects\Grj\Source Code\Rail\Source\trunk\Grj.Rail.Services\Impl\ReportService.cs:line 72
   at Grj.Rail.Services.Impl.ReportService.GetDayPlanReport(Int32 ticketOrderId, String dayPlanDate) in C:\VS Projects\Grj\Source Code\Rail\Source\trunk\Grj.Rail.Services\Impl\ReportService.cs:line 138
   at Grj.Rail.Controllers.TicketOrderController.DayPlan(Int32 ticketOrderId) in C:\VS Projects\Grj\Source Code\Rail\Source\trunk\Grj.Rail\Controllers\TicketOrderController.cs:line 628
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

**SSRS Error log**

```
library!ReportServer_0-105!2268!06/25/2013-13:18:45:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.String.GetStringForStringBuilder(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.GetNewString(String currentString, Int32 requiredLength)
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(String value)
   at System.IO.StringWriter.Write(String value)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextEncoder.Write(String text)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ParameterInfo.WriteValueToXml(XmlTextWriter xml, Object val)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ParameterInfo.WriteToXml(XmlTextWriter xml, Boolean writeTransientState)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ParameterInfoCollection.ToXml(Boolean usedInQueryValuesOnly, Boolean writeTransientState, Boolean convertToString)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ParameterInfoCollection.ToXml(Boolean usedInQueryValuesOnly)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportItem.get_EffectiveParamsXml()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.DatabaseSessionStorage.AddNewSession(SessionReportItem sessionReport)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.CreateNewSessionAction.Save()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
```

**Web.Config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ReportExecutionServiceSoap" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://grj-report01:80/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="ReportExecutionServiceSoap" 
                contract="Reporting.ReportExecutionServiceSoap" 
                name="ReportExecutionServiceSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**ReportService**

```
    using (var reportingServices = new Reporting.ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient("ReportExecutionServiceSoap"))
    {
        System.Net.NetworkCredential clientCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(railConfig.ReportingServicesUserName, railConfig.ReportingServicesPassword);
        reportingServices.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
        reportingServices.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = clientCredentials;
        reportingServices.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = true;

        ServerInfoHeader serverInfoHeader;
        ExecutionInfo executionInfo;
        ExecutionHeader executionHeader = reportingServices.LoadReport(null, report, null, out serverInfoHeader, out executionInfo);

        if (parameters != null && parameters.Any())
        {
            reportingServices.SetExecutionParameters(executionHeader, null, parameters, null, out executionInfo);
        }

        reportingServices.Render(executionHeader, null, format, null, out output, out extension, out mimeType, out encoding, out warnings, out streamIds);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue now and the problem was the date format of one of the parameters. Once i sorted this out the report ran fine in IE. Not sure why it would work in Firefox with the wrong format.